# simple regular expression - match specific url

Tags: regex, joomla

I'm a noob when it comes to Regular Expressions. I'm using Joomla and the Advanced Module Manager to publish a module to a specific url.

I want to publish a module only to the url `/tv-show` and not `/tv-show/anthingthing-else/blahblah`

I thought the way to do it is `/tv-show*` but obviously not, since it still publishes to other urls with /tv-show on the beginning.

I tried many variations, please tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

/tv-show$

The dollar matches the end of a string.

Comment: Awesome, yes this works :) thanks very much. I did come across this during my Googling but assumes 'string' ment a line of code!, woops. Thanks so much :)